# Create property setter directly in VB

Tags: vb.net

In VB.Net, a property is basically two methods, get_property and set_property, but there has to be more to it than that, because if you create the method names directly, it isn't treated as a property by other classes.

So, obviously some meta data is being added, attributes or something.  Is it possible to add this meta data by hand when writing a method? If so, how?  I found the MethodSemanticsAttributes, but couldn't apply it directly.

Edit:  Some code to show what is typically happens and what I am after.

```
Public Property MyProperty As String  ' auto property
```

Not using autoproperties the above becomes:

```
private _MyProperty As String
Public Property MyProperty As String
    Get
        Return _MyProperty
    End Get
    Set (ByVal value As String)
        _MyProperty = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Both of the above get turned into

```
 private _MyProperty As String
 Public Function get_MyProperty As String
   Return _MyProperty
 End Function
 Public Sub set_MyProperty(ByVal value As String)
    _MyProperty = value
 End Sub
```

Via reflection you can actually get a reference to the above methods and call them, so the above actually does happen.  But something else obviously happens as well, because if I write the above two methods, they don't get treated as a single property, they get treated as two methods.

My question is what is that something else? My goal would be to do the something else and then be able to tweak some things, to produce code that you normally can't.

Comment: It is not clear the exact point of your question (i.e., why do you want to know about this). In any case, your concerns don't seem motivated: even by ignoring the fact that in VB.NET you write the `Property` keyword (more than enough for the VS parser to know that this is something different), just with a get/set might also be enough. Visual Studio (and the VB.NET compiler) deliver their understanding on account of a given set of rules, which do not have necessarily to share with you (i.e., output meta data).

Comment: `a property is basically two methods`  *inside* or wrapped by `Property/End Property`.   A property  compiles to different code than a pseudo setter/getter pair.  The lack of Property semantics can actually be distracting: ExtenderProviders work off Setxxx/Getxxx pairs which together could be considered a property, but they arent

Comment: @varocarbas: actually they do have to share, if they want to allow other people to develop compilers that work with their tools, and apparently they do.  Not that I am writing a compiler.

Comment: Actually they are currently sharing everything (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn -> VB.NET & C# compilers; there are another 2 respositories for the whole .NET). If you want to build a compiler inspired in the VB.NET one, just start from its actual code which is open source and written in VB.NET (from VS 2015). In any case and as a reaction to each single bit of code you write, the compiler performs tons of actions which don't output anything other than the final result (.exe., .dll or whatever file).

Comment: @varocarbas: yes, I know about roslyn. Again, I am **not** writing a compiler.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But you said "if they want to allow other people to develop compilers..." and that's why I pointed out Roslyn. Giving out the whole source code of their compiler is the maximum they can do to allow other people develop compilers; you cannot do anything on top of giving the whole source code. And as said, the compiler accounts for tooooons of information which cannot be stored in any intermediate file, otherwise they would be systematically generating versions of the whole source (which is very big) every time a compilation happens :).

Comment: @varocarbas: and my point is that the rules, and process, for declaring a method get_MyProperty as the getter for the property MyProperty is something they have to share, contray to your first comment.  It may be that they don't provide an alternate way of **generating** that metadata, but what it is, and where it goes is absolutely out there. And that is what I am looking for at the moment, what comes after that will depend upon what I find out.

Comment: What you are saying is the same that asking why an Integer variable behaves differently than a String variable (or a list and a function or anything else). Where is the matadata storing such a difference? There is no such a thing. The compiler is an application (and VS, the part for syntax highlighting another one) which performs tons of actions on account of lots of rules, about which the final user (= you) don't have any direct knowledge/control. Note that Roslyn is not just the open-source version of the compilers; it also includes a further layer of information...

Comment: ...I am not too interested in all this (more interested in changing things directly in .NET :)) and that's why I don't know too much about it. But you might be interested in learning about all what you can do with Roslyn from the point of view of analysing the compilation. There are many options, but I know that one of the things you can do is getting a whole picture of the analysis performed by the compiler of each bit. For example: firstly determining the namespace, then the class, then the variable, then the type of variable, etc. Just an application performing a complex analysis; no meta.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the "Property" keyword.

```
  private SomeLocalVariableOfThatObjectType as ObjectType      

  public property PropertyName as ObjectType
    Get
       return SomethingLocalVariableOfThatObjectType
    end get
    set (blah as ObjectType)
       SomeLocalVariableOfThatObjectType = blah
    end set
  end property
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP knows what a property is.

Comment: While I agree with you in general, you seem to be mixing C# semantics with your VB code. For example, in VB the first statement would be `Public Property PropertyName As ObjectType`

Comment: Good point, that's one hazard of being "Bi-lingual"  I've edited my answer.

Comment: the setter is wrong too: `Set (Value as ObjectType)`

Comment: The answer to my question is not the keyword `Property`.  The keyword Property is in fact exactly what I do **not** want

Answer (score 1):

Remember the VB.Net code is compiled first to an Intermediate Language (IL). The IL methods created by the compiler for a property in VB.Net use special names that would be illegal if you tried to create them with methods alone.

Comment: As I said in my question, the IL methods created have the names get_property and set_property, and you can certainly create methods with that name.  But that doesn't make them properties, hence my question.  Interestingly enough, if you try to create BOTH a property and the methods, you get a already declared error, but you only get it for the setter at actual build time if the parameter is ByRef.